# Where is a complex function continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following function:

$$f(z) = Log(z) \space for \space z \not \in  \Re$$
$$f(z) = -ln( |{z}|) \space otherwise$$

I am saying that the only place where it is not continuous on the complex plane is at $|z|=0$ or $\Re (z)=0$ as at all other points it is defined on the complex plane.

Is this correct or if not what is the correct way for determining continuity in the case

Comment: What branch of $Log$ did you choose? If it is the principal it seems to me that the function is not continuous for all real values of $z$

Comment: The principal branch

Comment: So it is not continuous for all real $z$: to be continuous a complex function must have smooth variations in a surrounding of the point we are interested in but for real $z>0$ we have that the function tends to $\ln(z)$ when going on a vertical line so it abruptly changes sign on the real axis; for real $z<0$, we have that the function is continuous on a ray going vertically from the real axis but the function has a $2\pi$ jump when the sign of the imaginary parte changes.